# How to get Blender 2.8 windows to load on multiple monitors after closing and reopening Blender 2.8?

Tags: interface

I have a dual display setup. I setup different windows on each, saved the default startup file.

When I reload Blender 2.8, the window for the secondary monitor appears on the primary monitor.

Is there a way to have that window for the secondary monitor permanently locked to the secondary monitor even after reloading Blender 2.8?

Thanks.

Comment: I only use Blender 2.79.  In that version one can "save as starting file" - can't you do that in 2.8 any more?  If it's not under the File menu, maybe you can do a search.

If you set up the scene as you need it, then save it as a starting file, it should reload the setup each time you open Blender.

Comment: Yes this happens by default on 2.79, saving startup file is enough. If it doesn't happen for 2.8 it is either a bug, or misconfigured startup file, or Windows itself interfering with window management. Did you turn on or off your monitor? Maybe window assigned it a different ID and Blender can no longer recognize as the same hardware

Comment: Thank you for the responses. It is interesting how this error o key happens with Blender as my numerous other apps like Cubase, DaVinci, Gimp, etc etc etc all have no issues. As for the startup file, how can I tell if it has an error in it? I have reverted back and and recreated the split to no avail. 
Must be a bug. Hmmmm. 
Any other thoughts?
Thanks again for the input. 